# AWS Network out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our web application has 5 pages (Signin, Dashboard, Map, Devices, Notification)

We have done the load test for this application, and load test script does the following:

1. Signin and go to Dashboard page
2. Click Map
3. Click Devices
4. Click Notification

We have a basic free plan in AWS.

While performing load test, till about 100 users, we didn’t get any error. please see the below image. We could see NetworkIn, CPUUtilization seems to be normal. But the NetworkOut showed 846K.

[image]

But when reach around 114 users, we started getting error in the map page (highlighted in red). During that time, it seems only NetworkOut is high. Please see the below image.

[image]

We want to know what is the optimal score for the NetworkOut, If this number is high, is there any way to reduce this number?

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately you have not supplied enough information for us to be able to assist you. Can you edit your question to provide more information? For example, what do you mean by "high value"? Can you show us a chart from CloudWatch? You were performing a **load test**, so presumably that is related. You'll need to investigate what the load test was doing and what the application was doing. It all depends on your particular application.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for taking time to help me out. Apologies for not providing enough details. Have edited the question and added more details. Could you please help me out. Please let me know if I have to provide more specific details.

Comment: What Instance Type are you using? The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%23featured) only offers a `t2.micro` — is that the Instance Type you are using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Yes we are using AWS free tier - t2.micro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `t2.micro` instance.

This instance type has **limitations on CPU** that means it is good for bursty workloads, but sustained loads will consume all the available CPU credits. Thus, it might perform poorly under sustained loads over long periods.

The instance also has **limited network bandwidth** that might impact the throughput of the server. While all Amazon EC2 instances have limited allocations of bandwidth, the `t2.micro` and `t2.nano` have particularly low bandwidth allocations. You can see this when copying data to/from the instance and it might be impacting your workloads during testing.

The `t2` family, especially at the low-end, is **not a good choice for production workloads**. It is great for workloads that are sometimes high, but not consistently high. It is also particularly low-cost, but please realise that there are trade-offs for such a low cost.

See:

- [Amazon EC2 T2 Instances – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/)
- [CPU Credits and Baseline Performance for Burstable Performance Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html)
- [Unlimited Mode for Burstable Performance Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html)

That said, the network throughput showing on the graphs is a result of your application. While the `t2` might be limiting the throughput, it is not responsible for the spike on the graph. For that, you will need to investigate the resources being used by the application(s) themselves.

Comment: Thanks John, This is our development environment, we are doing load test here to understand and monitor Network out, Network IN, CPU utilisation, so we can plan the better paid plan while going for the production. 

We want to know what is the optimal score for the NetworkOut, If this number is high, is there any way to reduce this number?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "optimal" number. It is just showing you the amount of network traffic that left the instance. If your application returns lots of data to requests, then this is to be expected. A video service would have a high number, a simple web page would have a low number.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOut` simply refers to volume of outgoing traffic from the instance. You reduce the requests you are sending from this instance to reduce the `NetworkOut` .So you may need to see which one of `click Map, Click Devices and Click Notification` is sending traffic outside of the instances. It may not necessarily related only to the number of users but a combination of number of users and application module.